# CSS: Right-sided navigation DIV to fill entire page height

Tags: html, css-position, css

I'm currently working on a new website: http://maartenlodewijk.nl/2013/

The light-grey bar on the right side (with the word "test" in it) is supposed to be my nav bar. I've been trying for days to get its height to fill the page height (not just browser height, but the entire page). Just as in this mockup I've made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zQdN.jpg

I've tried multiple ways now, from simple ones such as setting body and html height to 100% (No luck there) and a CSS hack such as here: ejeliot.com/samples/equal-height-columns/example-7.html (Which works, but a hack is really a last-resort option for me)

Here is my HTML and CSS code. In case youre wondering: Yes, I have both a wrapper and a container div, the wrapper centers the container, while the container maintains a fixed position within the wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Maarten Lodewijk // Home</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
    test
</div> <!-- end navigation -->

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <img src="images/headerpng.png" alt="Logo" border="0" />
    </div> <!-- header -->
    <div id="weclome">
    <img src="images/homemessagepng.png" width="645" height="203" alt="Maarten Lodewijk, Communication &amp; Multimedia Designer" /></div><!-- end welcome -->
    <div id="content">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
                <p>TEXT</p>

                <p>TEXT</p>

                <p>TEXT</p>
            </div><!-- end leftcolumn -->

    <div id="rightcolumn">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
            <table width="286" border=0>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="96">Mail:</td>
                <td width="180" class="rightalign">mail@maartenlodewijk.nl</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Telefoon:</td>
                <td class="rightalign">+31 6 348 268 52</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        <h1>HEADER</h1>
        <p>TEXT</p>

        <p>TEXT</p>

        <p>TEXT</p>


      </div><!-- end rightcolumn -->
    </div> <!-- end content -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* ----- TAGS -------*/

body {
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
    background: #e8e8eb url(images/bg.png) repeat-y;
    color: #666666;
}

html{
}
h1{
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #ff3366;
    padding-top:30px;
}



/* ----- LAY OUT -----*/
#wrapper{
    width:955px; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#container{
    width:645px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#content{
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

#navigation{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 16%;
    min-width: 163px;
    max-width:233;
    background-image:url(images/navbarbg.jpg);
    height: 100%;
}


#leftcolumn{
    width:286px;
    float:left;
}

#rightcolumn{
    width:286px;
    float:right;
}

/* ----- CLASSES -----*/
.rightalign{
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: why your navigation div is outside from wrapper?

Comment: </div id="wrapper"> <!-- end wrapper -->
this is not right way of closing why you are giving id name on the closing tag?

Comment: Thats a small error that I've already fixed yesterday. I copied most this HTML code from a post I made yesterday on a different forum. (updated HTML in this post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i saw your layout so it's good if you give `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute;` to your **#navigation** DIV. Write like this:

```
#navigation{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 16%;
    min-width: 163px;
    max-width:233;
    background-image:url(images/navbarbg.jpg);
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Fiddled with the other answers for a whole evening, stopped caring about it and used this instead. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Please add a background color to `#wrapper` and see  your `#leftcolumn` and `#rightcolumn` are not in the `#wrapper` area. Maybe this is an issue in your template. Please check after fixing that.

If that won't work you can use jQuery to get heights dynamically and set the navigation height.

Answer (score 0):

There is big problem in this layout you are using background image on body tag which is `1920x99` so your body is reacting to this section only.

some quick changes make this working fine.
 please see my attached output i did these quick changes with developer tool. 
you should restructure the layout put everything inside wrapper and use float,position for the navigation and other section.

nothing is working together in your layout you should re-build it and use proper style for the every section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your menu to be ALWAYS visible you might wanna use the solution from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296343/1144057).

If you would simply like to extend your sidebar after a scroll - you need to use the so-called `css equal height columns` - here is an example of them: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/

Comment: Great article! I'm going to try this one as soon as I get home! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want equal height `#navigation` and `#wrapper` apply this class `.equal_height` and

use this jquery function with library file

```
function equalHeight(group) {
   tallest = 0;
   group.each(function() {
      thisHeight = $(this).height();
      if(thisHeight > tallest) {
         tallest = thisHeight;
      }
   });
   group.height(tallest);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   equalHeight($(".equal_height"));
});
```

May it will help you.